# Bitwise operators LinqDataSource Where

Tags: asp.net, bit-manipulation, where-clause, linqdatasource

I have a byte column called 'Type' in my MS Server database. On my Asp.net page I have a ListView and a LinqDataSource. The 'Type' column is different enum flags.

I would like to check specific bits in column 'Type' in my LinqDataSource Where property.

I tried with: (Check first bit)

```
Type == (Type | 1)
Type = (Type | 1)
Type | 1 == Type

Type &amp; 1 == 1
Type & 1 == 1
(Type &amp; 1) == 1
(Type & 1) == 1
```

and so on...

I get two kinds of exceptions:

- Operator incompatible with string and
- boolean Excepted ')'

I have checked google and msdn docs without luck.

Comment: What type is the Type member in your data context?

Comment: The type is byte so I don't know where the string comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the LinqDataSource OnSelecting event now. It is not as clean though.